# how to show a wide box when mouse hover on bootstrap navigation menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="test"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code I have create a bootstrap navigation menu i.e. menu1, menu2 & menu3. Now, I want that when I hover on any navigation menu then it show a box at the bottom of the menu for example:https://www.flipkart.com/. So, How can I do this ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Use this example [reference](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/large-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="test"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            Button
            </button>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-list">
                <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-list {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown {

  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-list{
  display:block;
}
```

Here jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mhz86puo/2/